# How to create an update installer with NSIS?

Tags: installation, nsis

Currently I have an installer created using NSIS. Now I want to create an update installer which updates the application to the newer version by copying only the changed files. The target platform is windows.

Answer (score 0):

The question is too broad. It will probably get flagged as invalid. BTW,

- if your installer overwrites all files, it could work as a not-very-clean updater too.
- Ultimately, your installer/updater should check on start, if the program is already installed, and if necessary, uninstall it before installing the new version. I recommend it calls the uninstaller installed by your first installed, and then performs a regular install. You should keep registry records if you want to keep current settings.

Comment: The existing version should not be uninstalled.The requirement is to make changes to the existing files in the currently installed version if they have been changed in the latest version.If there are any new files in the newer version add them.

Comment: NSIS overwrites files, so if you install a newer version over an older one, it will replace all files, which is what you need. Anyway, you can control this behavior with the `[SetOverwrite](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#asetoverwrite)` command.

Comment: That worked..Thank you.How can I delete the extra files from previous installation which are not the part of current installation.Can I delete the files based on time stamp?